# Cambiar color de ngx-pagination

Tags: css, angular, angular6

Quiero cambiar el color de fondo que pone por defecto ngx-pagination con angular 6. El color que pone de fondo es azul y me gustaría cambiarlo a rojo.

Mi código de ngx-pagination:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado de la ngx-pagination:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer el cambio de color a rojo?

Comment: Traduce la pregunta por favor, estás en Stack Overflow en Español.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prueba con esta regla de `css` con el operador `::ng-deep` a ver si te funciona como quieres:

```
.custom-pagination ::ng-deep .ngx-pagination .current {
    background: red;
}
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias eso funciona, solo que tienes que tener instalado el jquery en el proyecto, el cual no tenía desde un principio.

Comment: Si, disculpa se me olvido comentar lo de jQuery. En todo caso he estado mirando la documentación al respecto y parece ser que el operador '/deep/' va a ser eliminado de los navegadores principales, prueba con las alternativas a '/deep/' que son '>>>' y '::ng-deep'. Saludos